# Selenium - org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I can run a single test, but when trying to execute the second, this exception is thrown.

The problem is that the driver I pass through all pages is static, and when I close the browser between tests, it is set to null and is not working anymore, only for the first scenario.

My doubts are how to modify the code to make it run for all tests, closing the browser in between.

```
package com.***.pageobjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Browser {

    private static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

      public static WebDriver driver() {    
          return driver;
      }

      public static void open(String url) {    
          driver.get(url);
      }

      public static void close() {    
          driver.quit(); 
          System.out.println(driver.toString());
      }

}




public class LoginPage extends LoadableComponent<LoginPage> {

    private WebDriver driver;

    static String url = "***";
    private static String title = "***";



    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); 
        }

      @Override  
      protected void load() {    
          Browser.open(url);
          driver.manage().window().maximize();  
      }

      @Override  
      protected void isLoaded() throws Error {    
          assertTrue("Login page not loaded",        
                  driver.getTitle().equals(title));  
      } 


      public MainPage MainPage() {    
          MainPage mainpage = new MainPage(driver);    
          return mainpage;
          }
}


public class MainPage {

     private WebDriver driver;


        @FindBy(id = "user-userName")
        private WebElement userName;

        @FindBy(id = "password") 
        private WebElement pwd;

        @FindBy(id = "btnLogin") 
        private WebElement buttonlogin;

        public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {    
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }


          public void login(String user, String password)
          {
              userName.sendKeys(user);
              pwd.sendKeys(password); 
              buttonlogin.click();

          }
}

public class areaPersonalSuite {



    @cucumber.api.java.Before
    public void beforeScenario() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver");

    }

     @Given("Soy cliente") 
      public void soyCliente() {    

     }

    @When("^Accedo a mi Area Personal con usuario (.*) y password (.*)$")         
    public void accedoAreaPersonal(String user, String password){
          // Create an instance of Home page     
          LoginPage loginpg = new LoginPage(Browser.driver());
          // Navigate to the Home page      
          loginpg.get();
          loginpg.MainPage().login(user,password);

      }

    @Then ("el sistema muestra mi dirección, teléfono y email correctamente")
    public void direccionTelefonoEmail(){
        LoginPage telefono = new LoginPage(Browser.driver());
        telefono.MainPage().addressCheck();



      @cucumber.api.java.After
      public void afterScenario() {
          Browser.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct, your problem is more about driver management. I would suggest to use proven existing framework like [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) which takes care of driver management.

It will allow you to configure driver it through properties or from run configuration xml file and will create driver instance for test case as per run configuration. You can run same test on different browser as well without code modification.

```
public class LoginPage extends WebDriverTestPage{
    @FindBy("locator.in.repository")
    private WebElement ele;

    public WebElement getEle(){
      return ele;
    }
}
```

You also can use BDD from QAF of use [gherkin with QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf-gherkin-client.html). You can check [sample project](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project) or  here is [QAF gherkin example](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/releases/download/2.1.9-RC2/QAFGherkin.zip)